# What is the time period in which an interaction with a π-meson takes place?

Tags: nuclear-physics, strong-force, mesons

The longer-range inter-nucleon force is not a direct result of the gluon field, but is indirectly affected by a quark-antiquark pair (meson).

If this ‘residual’ strong interaction between nucleons is mediated by a π-meson, then what is the maximum time period in which the interaction takes place?

If we assume that it moves at a velocity v → c, then what is the
range of the interaction?